# How can I add a new page on Symfony 4 without any 404 error?

Tags: php, symfony, http-status-code-404, laragon

I'm working on an imported project on Symfony 4.2 with Encore build system.

I installed all the module and everything is working fine.

But when I want to add a new page (requetes), I always get an 404 error.

Here is the project : https://github.com/LaboratoirePLH/ERC-MAP

- PHP 7.2.11
- PostgreSQL 9.6 with PostGIS 2.4
- Symfony 4.2 with Encore build system
- Bootstrap 4.2
- jQuery 3
- ChosenJS for jQuery (autocomplete combo box)
- DataTables for jQuery (improved data tables)

I'm running PosteGre with Laragon.

I tried to ensure mod_rewrite on apache2.

I tried too to put an .httaccess file on the public/, still not working.

I checked the route with "php bin/console debug:route" and she is listed

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNTra.png (I can't post the image I need more reputation)

The RequetesController.php :

```
/**
     * Page queries
     *
     * @Route("/requetes", name="requetes")
     */

     public function index(){

         return $this->render('requetes/index.html.twig');

     }
```

And the twig, in the requetes folder :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello {{ $requetes }}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

With the link "https://127.0.0.1:8000/requetes" I got a 404 error, and with "https://127.0.0.1:8000/" it's working.

I'm a beginner on Symfony and I really need your help.

Comment: Maybe because your templates doesn't exist in the place 'templates/requetes/index.html.twig' ?

Comment: can you post the contents of config/routes/annotations.yaml and/or config/routes.yaml

Comment: Thanks for your help !
My template exist in the right place, I checked this before testing any solution.

Here is the content of the config/routes.yaml :
https://i.imgur.com/Xla0USA.png

Answer (score 0):

What you can try it's to call your twig like that :

```
return $this->render('requetes');
```

if it exists it have to display the page. If it exists can you show us the full error message ?

Comment: I can't comment ATM not enough reputation

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Here is the error : https://i.imgur.com/u3BpkD6.png
It doesn't work with your call :/

Comment: Here is the error on the console :

"Apr 15 08:51:56 |ERROR| PHP    Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /requetes"" at C:\Bureau 2\Stage\Site\3\ERC-MAP\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\EventListener\RouterListener.php line 139 path="C:\\laragon\\bin\\php\\php-7.2.11-Win32-VC15-x64\\php-cgi.exe" php="7.2.11"

Answer (score 0):

What is the content of your public/.htaccess file? Could you try with this one which come from the apache-pack recipe :

https://github.com/symfony/recipes-contrib/blob/master/symfony/apache-pack/1.0/public/.htaccess

---

EDIT :

Try to reformat your annotations ans action like this:

```
/**
 * Page queries
 *
 * @Route("/requetes", name="requetes")
 */
public function index()
{
    return $this->render('requetes/index.html.twig');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I have the same problem with this htaccess file

Comment: Does your GIthub repo is up to date? Because I can't see it

Comment: I'm taking back the project and can't push in this.
I created a new github repo :

https://github.com/Aleridia/stage

Comment: I just realized it can't be related to your server config (.htaccess) because you use the Symfony built-in server. But I can't find your action. In which controller did you put your "requetes" action?

Comment: Right. My fault too I wasn't clear about this subject.
My "requetes" controller is in "src/Controller/RequetesController.php"

Comment: Yes that's what I guessed but the controller isn't in your Github repository

Comment: I'm sorry I thought that the push will add all the file in the creation of the git.
I pushed it, thanks a lot for your help.
The git :  github.com/Aleridia/stage

Comment: I can't find the problem. The biggest problem I can see is the annotations of your action that is not well formatted. Maybe try to organize this better. It could be the problem

Comment: Do I need to organize better my RequestController.php ? Or the entiere project ?
Thanks you for taking time on my problem !

Comment: Just this controller and in particular your annations on your index action. I will edit my answer to show you how it should be formatted

Comment: I changed my code. It's cleaner, I'll rememner it for my next php files.
The problem is still here, I think I made a mistake in the Symfony's installation.

Answer (score 0):

In your project directory create this file if it does not exist :
**project_dir/public/.htaccess** and add the following content to the file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I tried but it changed nothing.
My .htaccess is in the projecy_dir/public/ on my symfony project. Is that the right folder ?